# CakePHP 3 AJAX with Pagination

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.2

I am new to CakePHP. I have installed CakePHP 3.2.10.

I have implemented simple AJAX calls. I have also implemented pagination in normal view.

Now I want to show records, loading with AJAX and using pagination.

Can anyone guide me how to go about doing this?

I have referred to the cookbook but did not get proper information.

Do I create a normal action and view with pagination code ?

Comment: Start from: make it work without ajax (which should be easy, because it should already be work). Your code needs to be in the question for readers to help you.

Comment: [Here](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples) are some examples along with lots of more code and a blog post to find more about AJAX and CakePHP.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can use liveQuery Javascript library. you can download from [here](https://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/)

1. And add this library code in your CakePHP template layout in
2. Wrap your listings and pagination links in div tag apply **id="wrapper"**.
3. add this function in common javascript code which must be load in
   page end before end of body tag

Add Below Code in Javascript

```
function ajaxPageLoader(request_url) {
        console.log("Content loading from : "+request_url);
        $("#wrapper").load(request_url + " #wrapper", function() {
            window.history.pushState({}, "", request_url);
            console.log("Content loaded");
        });
    }
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('your_pagination_link_selector').livequery(function() {
            $(this).unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                ajaxPageLoader($(this).attr('href'));
                return false;
            })
       });
    });
```